# How to code SQL statements from generated Crystal

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Here we have generated Crystal SQL and I need to make these same on AS/400 db2 for performance reasons. How do you code  these in AS/400 SQL?

```
TodaysDate 
 like  and
 <>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to describe in user terms what you are trying to do?  For example, find all invoices issued today, or omit all orders with a delivery date other than today.

Comment: the report is showing all orders that have some error on it and therefore the order is halted. this report will show according to user, dates etc. these 'orders on correction hold'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ... 
  from order_table 
  where order_date = current date and
        status_code in ('E', '1', 'X') and
        user = 'BLOGGS';
```

The [DB2 for i Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzintro.htm) manual may be helpful.

Comment: Buck, how do I create a view against this table?